# Execute a linux command inside a python program

Tags: python, subprocess

I am writing a python program in linux.

In my python program i need to execute a linux command in another working directory , from inside the python program itself.

Example:
My program test.py is in directory dir1/dir2.

./wlst.sh is a program in dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4.

So i need to execute .wlst.sh in dir4 from the python program located in dir2.

How can this be done?

Comment: I assume you have googled and found the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module.  What problems are you having with it?

Answer (score 3):

```
import subprocess
try:
  output = subprocess.check_output(
    [ './wlst.sh' ],
    cwd='dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4',
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as problem:
  print "Error", problem.returncode
  print "  while calling subprocess, output was:", problem.output
else:
  print "No error while calling subprocess, output was:", output
```

I have to mention that this captures all the output of the subprocess, so if this subprocess does lots and lots (and maybe will never terminate), this will fill up your RAM.  Consider using `check_call()` instead of `check_output()` in this case, maybe with redirecting the output to `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['./wlst.sh'], cwd='dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4')
```

Comment: Using `chdir` will have the obvious side effect; better use optional parameter `cwd=` for `call()`.

Answer (score -2):

```
    import os ,subprocess
    os.chdir("dir3/dir4")
    os.system("./wlst.sh")
```

or else u can use subprocess

```
    os.chdir("dir3/dir4")
    subprocess.call("./wlst.sh")
```

Comment: Using `chdir` will have the obvious side effect.